# How do i get a colored diff for last changes in git on the console?

Tags: git, console

I would like to be able to see the last changes in a git repository from within a console.

Is it possible to get a GUI-like output in colour, side-by-side and only the last 10 commits?

maybe this somehow works on debian too:
http://heipei.net/2009/01/29/git-full-length-side-by-side-diffs/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

'git difftool' allows you to do this.

You can also use your favorite difftool by doing 'git difftool --tool=vimdiff --no-prompt'

And you can compare revisions like other diff comands

'git difftool HEAD~10 HEAD'

Comment: I did that and it looks fine, but i cannot quit the diftool anymore, it auto restarts

Comment: Autostarts? If you put no prompt, maybe it's displaying you all the files that have a difference if you didn't specify a particular file. The --no-prompt option doesn't ask before opening a file, if you don't use it, you are asked if you want to open each particular file that is different. If you have too many files maybe the best option is to specify which files you want to check.  'git difftool --tool=vimdiff --no-prompt main.h *.cpp'

Comment: It's not quite as intuitive as `tig` but I like the **side-by-side view**. What would I have to enter on the console to see just the last commit side-by-side and how do I quit back to the console then?

Answer (score 1):

I heartily recommend [tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/) for a text-based git UI.

Comment: this looks really intuitive, only a shame, that it has no side-by-side view, or can you do that too somehow?